# SELECT query showing in processlist but not completing/executing

Tags: mysql

There's a SELECT query in MySQL processlist which is stuck (or maybe not?)

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;

| Id        | User | Host       | db     | Command | Time    | State        | Info                                                 |
| 537478557 | root | localhost  | my_DB  | Query   |       0 | Sending data | select * from my_DB.T_final where name in ('AB1234') |
```

I fired multiple SHOW PROCESSLIST queries over a 15 minute period and

- Time value is always zero
- Id is the same (confirming its the same query)
- I ran the same SELECT query on MySQL command line (while the original query was still showing in the processlist) and I got the result instantaneously.

I've killed the query now but would like an explanation on this behaviour.

Comment: I've never seen, that the time value stays at 0. But now that you've killed it, all information that could solve this riddle is gone anyway.

Comment: In the future, remember to inspect `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` and also check for filesystem problems. Usually this symptom shows for full-table scans.

Comment: @fancyPants the query was actually killed by another admin :(  I wanted to see if I could write lock the table and had few other tests in mind but he thought it was a bug (fair assumption) and killed it

Comment: @IVOGELOV will do 